# UDP Receive, never receive last few packets

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, udp

I'm using a C++ UDP socket to send an OpenCV Mat image to an android device (which received using a UDP Datagramsocket). I'm converting the image into a Uchar buffer ( size of Uchar = 1), and sending it over UDP in chunks of 1024.

The send process works using a local host c++ socket, but not using the Android Java Datagram socket. On the Android device, I never only receive around 2200 out of 2304 packets. I know that there always is packet loss when using UDP, but when I reconstruct the image with just the received bytes, I get the complete image, except the last couple of rows of pixels from the bottom.

If it were the case of packet loss over the network, i assume the missing packets would be scattered all throughout the image and not literally in the sequence of the last 100 datagram packets.

Could it be the case that the sizes of the received elements don't match ? 
Has anyone encountered any similar problems?

C++ Send:

```
  uchar *sendBuffer = (uchar*)malloc(imgSize*sizeof(uchar));
  int  bufferSize = imgSize*sizeof(uchar);     //Sizeof(uchar) returns 1.
  int datagramSize = 1024;

  for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += datagramSize) {
        sendto(sock, sendBuffer + i, datagramSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        usleep(1000);
    }
```

Java Android Receive:

```
// WIDTH x HEIGHT x CHANNELS:
int width = 1024;
int height = 768;
int numChannels = 3;
int totalSize = width*height*numChannels;

int datagramSize = 1024;

//DECLARE RECEIVE BUFFER:
byte[] totalBuffer = new byte[totalSize];
byte[] recBuffer = new byte[datagramSize];

int byte_rec = 0;

//CALL RECEIVE ON SOCKET:
for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i += byte_rec) {

        //CALL RECEIVE:
        dSocket.receive(dPacket);
        byte_rec = dPacket.getLength();

        //MEMCOPY DATAGRAM INTO IMAGE BUFFER:
        //System.arraycopy(recBuffer, 0, totalBuffer, i, recSize );
        System.arraycopy(dPacket.getData(), dPacket.getOffset(), totalBuffer, i, byte_rec );

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you add some metadata to your packets, so you, for example, have some idea about which packets actually arrived and which did not? If you're sending a picture spanning 2000+ datagrams over what I expect is a wireless network...

Comment: I receive the complete image, except the bottom (100*1024) pixels. I've tested this by displaying the packets I received. 
I figured that this means that the last packets didn't arrive . Or not ?

Comment: Since your code doesn't exit until you've received the expected number of bytes, the behavior you're describing seems to be impossible with the given code.